# Make a dynamically re-sized, BufferedImage, scroll, that renders actively

Tags: java, canvas, bufferedimage

I have stumbled upon a bottle neck that I would love to fix.

I need to make a `BufferedImage` grow with time, but the Buffered image should support scrolling as my application requires that the Bufferedimage grow a significant size over time. However the draw calls are not done by the event dispatch thread.

I have a while loop that performs the render calls. What I attempted was to create an instance of a `Canvas` and add it to a `JScrollPane` however when I take this approach, the JScrollPane performs its own draw calls and I am not sure how the JScrollPane will detect that the canvas has resized at runtime.

The other issue is that since within the canvas I use a BufferedImage to draw onto, I cannot get it to resize with a temporary BufferedImage.

Here is how I attempted to create a new, larger BufferedImage

```
if(needsToBeResized)
{
    BufferedImage temporaryBufferedImag = 
    new BufferedImage(originalImage + extraSpace, height, originalImage.getType());

    Graphics g2d = temporaryBufferedImag.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(originalImage, 0,0,null);

    //I presume that this should copy the graphics object with the original img
    originalImage = temporaryBufferedImag;
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

If it helps I am developing an oscilloscope type application that needs to be able to keep plotting values real-time but I also need to be able to show the history of values.

Comment: So long as you are modifying the values returned by `getPreferredSize` and calling `revalidate`, you should be able to get the `Canvas` to grow.  In this case, I would recommend using the `BufferStrategy` support available in `Canvas` rather than relying on `BufferedImage` for painting

Comment: Well I do have a buffer strategy, the reason for using the BufferedImage is because I want the drawing to be double buffered.

Comment: What do you think the `BufferStrategy` is doing?  It's providing a basic page flipping bugger (or double buffer) based on your needs....

Comment: Now that I am considering it, will the BufferStrategy be able to grow dynamically as long as I setPreferredSize() on the canvas? if this is the case I could rid myself of having to create a larger BufferedImage.

Comment: Yes, the size of the buffer will be directly depend on the current size of the `Canvas`, so long as you are allowing the `JScrollPane` to revalidate the layout, it should work fine.

Comment: And yes now that I think about it, Its pretty obvious that BufferStrategy should be buffered....

Comment: I tried implementing a JScrollPane but have the same issue, that when ever revalidate is called on it, it clears the screen. I would like the old content to stay and the new content to continue being rendered on the added space

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Render each interval in its own "mini" BufferedImage. So, for a gross example, say you render every second, and you want to show 20 seconds of history.

So, you render your current second in to a "1 second sized" image. Then you take your cache of the images from the previous 19 seconds, and you stamp them all together, one after the other in to your new total image, and display that.

Next second, you drop off the oldest image, create a new one, stick it on the end, rinse and repeat.

If your overall frame size changes, when you get to render all of the pieces all over again…c'est la vie.

Obviously you will be sampling more than once a second, but you get the gist of it.

All this assumes this is cheaper than simply re-rendering the entire thing from scratch each time.